# Frame breaks inside mdframed environment with beamer class

Tags: beamer, page-breaking, mdframed

The `mdframed` environment fails to break into several pages (slides) when used in a `frame` environment from the `beamer` class.

In the other hand, the `boitecoloriee` environment from the `boites` package can be broken into several pages.

Here is a document that demonstrates the issue. It should not be compiled directly into pdf because `boitecoloriee` uses `pstricks`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor,boites,boites_exemples,pstricks}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Using \texttt{boitecoloriee}}
  \begin{boitecoloriee}
    \lipsum[1-2]
  \end{boitecoloriee}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Using \texttt{mdframed}}
  \begin{mdframed}
    \lipsum[1-2]
  \end{mdframed}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Maybe is there a way to fix `mdframed` to work in slides too. Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I must answer this question with: You can't do this.

The contents of a beamer frame will be saved in a savebox. `mdframed` does the same. You can't combine the splitting algorithm of `\vsplit` which is used by `beamer` and `mdframed`.

The package `boites` uses an other algorithm. It prints the contents line by line and so you can handle the page breaks in `beamer`.

Comment: Does this same explanation also apply to the `tcolorbox` package?

Comment: @Romildo: Yes. It uses nearly the same algorithm.