# Break a large theorem using mdframed on beamer

Tags: beamer, theorems, mdframed

I am using `mdframed` to write theorems and I've been dealing with this theorem that is quite long and hao 4 equations in it. I have tried using `[allowframebreaks]` and using `\framebreak` in a specific place of the theorem but nothing has worked.

This is my theorem environment and the text of the theorem

```
\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}

\newcounter{theo}
\newenvironment{theo}[1][]{%
\stepcounter{theo}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=cyan!50]
     {\strut Teorema~\thetheo};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=cyan!50]
    {\strut Teorema~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=-3pt,linecolor=cyan!50,%
   linewidth=2pt,innerlinewidth =2pt, backgroundcolor=gray!10 ,topline=true,
   frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
}
{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{frame}
\begin{theo}
      Some text
      \begin{equation}\label{2.5}
      \dfrac{\partial p}{\partial D}=\dfrac{1}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\nu_{i}+f''_{i}(q_{i})}-G'(p)}>0    
      \end{equation}
      \noindent y
      \begin{equation}\label{2.6}
      \dfrac{\partial p}{\partial \nu_{i}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{q_{i}}{\nu_{i}+f''_{i}(q_{i})}}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\nu_{j}+f''_{j}(q_{j})}-G'(p)}>0.    
      \end{equation}
      More text
      \begin{equation}\label{2.7}
      \dfrac{\partial q_{i}(D, \nu_{1}, \ldots , \nu_{n}) }{\partial \nu_{i}}=\dfrac{-q_{i}}{\nu_{i}+f_{i}''(q_{i}) }  \left[  \dfrac{ \sum\limits_{\substack{i=1 \\ i \neq k}}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\nu_{i}+f''_{i}(q_{i})}-G'(p)   }{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\nu_{i}+f''_{i}(q_{i})}-G'(p)}   \right] <0
       \end{equation}
       \noindent y
       \begin{equation}\label{2.8}
       \dfrac{\partial q_{i}(D, \nu_{1}, \ldots , \nu_{n}) }{\partial \nu_{k}}=\dfrac{1}{\nu_{k}+f_{k}''(q_{k})  } \left[ \dfrac{ \dfrac{q_{k}}{\nu_{k}+f''_{k}(q_{k})}  }{  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\nu_{k}+f''_{k}(q_{k})}-G'(p) } \right] >0.
       \end{equation}
\end{theo}
\end{frame}
```

Is there anyway to break this theorem in two frames and still be within this mdframe?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Must it be on separate frames? Could you put it on different slides belonging to the same frame? If you want help with it, it would be helpful if you would make your code compilable so people can copy-paste and play with it.

Comment: Unfortuately `mdframed` splitting doesn't work in `beamer`.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52386/15925, which suggests some alternatives.