# Newenvironment In Beamer

Tags: beamer, mdframed, examples

A minimal example of my code is shown. The problem is, first of all, that the space between the title of the example and the description of the problem is too large. So I want to reduce the space, but I cannot figure out how. Secondly, if the example is too long it should continue on the next page, but the command `allowframebreaks` does not do the job.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,
]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

% Example enviroment
\newcounter{exm}[section]\setcounter{exm}{0}
\renewcommand{\theexm}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{exm}}
\newenvironment{exm}[3][]{%
\refstepcounter{exm}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=white!100]
{\strut \small{Eksempel~\theexm: #2}};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
%\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
%\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=white!100]
{\strut \small{Eksempel~\theexm:~#1: #2}};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=0pt,linecolor=green!80,%
skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=0pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=green,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=0pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=3pt,
innerbottommargin=0pt,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{exm:#3}}{\end{mdframed}}

\newcommand{\exam}[4]{%
\begin{exm}{#1}{#2}
\begin{small}
\begin{textit}
#3  
\end{textit} \\[0.2cm]
\textbf{Solution:} \\
#4
\end{small}
\end{exm}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Frametitle}
\exam{Title of the example}{LabelName}{Descibtion of the problem...}{A very long text.A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text.A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text.A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text.A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text.A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text.A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text.A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text.A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text.A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text.A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text.}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52386/frame-breaks-inside-mdframed-environment-with-beamer-class -> If you want automatic frame breaks (which are evil), don't use `mdframed`

Comment: `\begin{small}` is, in my opinion, bad enough. However, others see that differently. But `\begin{textit}` makes no sense at all. `\textit` takes an argument. It does not permit paragraph breaks. It is not a switch.